# How to avoid insert_image_dimensions only for certain tags

Tags: apache, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I wish to use

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters image_rewrite
```

As well as:

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_image_dimensions
```

But there are certain img within my page where I didn't want the latter to be applied, while not losing the first.

If I avoid the rewrite with:

```
<img ... pagespeed_no_transform />
```

Compression and resize will be also skipped, even if I wanted just to avoid insert_image_dimensions.

Any solutions? (rather than manually resizing and compressing)